# Kernel configurations for lxc

Tags: linux, kernel, containers, virtualization, lxc

I am configuring Linux kernel 3.10.31ltsi and want to add the needed support for LXC, as far as I understood, cgroups and namespaces shall be available for LXC, but what are the configurations in menuconfig that need to be included?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a script called "lxc-checkconfig" (which is part of LXC) to check whether your kernel supports or not all required settings; see
https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/manpages/man1/lxc-checkconfig.1.html

As a side note, I think that LXC uses by default all namespaces; this means that you should set
CONFIG_UTS_NS, CONFIG_IPC_NS, CONFIG_USER_NS, CONFIG_PID_NS, 
CONFIG_NET_NS, and the mount namesapces (forgot it's config entry).
Regarding cgroups - not sure, probably the memory, cpu and I/O cgroups controllers are mandatory, and maybe some more; use the lxc-checkconfig script.